# How to print Arabic text in Zebra ZQ220 using "esc_pos_utils" package in flutter

Tags: flutter, printing, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, escpos

I'm using a printer: Zebra ZQ220

I'm currently using:

- esc_pos_utils: ^1.1.0
- flutter_pos_printer_platform: ^1.0.12

The printer prints English successfully. but when we try to print Arabic, it prints strange characters not the arabic text.

I tried two ways to send encoded string:

First:

```
final arabicText = utf8.encode('شركه هنا');
Uint8List uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(arabicText);
bytes += generator.textEncoded(uint8List);
```

First way output (utf8_Arabic):
[image]

======================================================

Second:

```
final List<int> codeUnits = 'شركه هنا'.codeUnits;    
final Uint8List unit8List = Uint8List.fromList(codeUnits);
bytes += generator.textEncoded(unit8List);
```

Second way output (codeUnits_Arabic):
[image]

Also, I set the Code page to "CP1252", but this code page works fine in English not Arabic.

Comment: This is a different printer vendor and model, but probably the same issue. [How to print Arabic letters with thermal printer using Flutter esc_pos_printer library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66355251/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found some useful Flutter SDKs for Thermal Printers that offer support for multiple languages including Arabic language:

- [bluetooth_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_thermal_printer) - This is a Flutter plugin that allows you to use a Bluetooth thermal printer on Android device.
- [blue_print_pos](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_print_pos) - This is a Flutter plugin that enables you to use a
  POS (point of sale) system on both Android and iOS device.
  This is the updated forked [blue_print_pos SDK](https://github.com/ankush-ppie/blue_print_pos/) which I used in Dec, 2022. You can use it without facing any issues.

Comment: This package is not being compiled.

Comment: run `flutter pub get` & 'flutter run'. for iOS, install pod first.

Comment: Yep, of course, I did this. Here is the error if you want to have a look: > No signature of method: build_2ygzesu3y6gr9h0cwn2zbcldh.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_2ygzesu3y6gr9h0cwn2zbcldh$_run_closure2) values: [build_2ygzesu3y6gr9h0cwn2zbcldh$_run_closure2@723adabf]

Comment: Error is due to internal issue of Android project build script (build.gradle). Please check this if useful in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67418660/no-signature-of-method-android-is-applicable-for-argument-types-exception-i

Comment: I checked the answers but had no luck. Is this repo being compiled on your machine? Maybe you can share what you changed specifically.

Comment: which package code you are looking for? blue_print_pos SDK ?

Comment: yes. blue_print_pos is being compiler. blue_print_pos SDK(your repo) is being compiled when I create a fresh Flutter project. The problem is you repo is being compiled with my current project. Maybe, if you changes are small, I can apple them by myself. 
Any other suggestion is appreciated. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: There is one solution, You can fork my repo & use code. If not works let me know. I will find another way.

Comment: Also you can check my commits & make changes in your code [commits](https://github.com/andriyoganp/blue_print_pos/compare/master...ankush-ppie:blue_print_pos:master)

Comment: Nope, it is not solved. I compiled the project. Apparently, the build problem happens because of a sub-dependency. After I compiled it, the code didn't print anything and gave 'context is not an activity error'. If you are available, I would like to take professional support from you. Please get in touch with me: emre.surk [at] gmail [dot] com
Thanks.