# How can i print arabic word in bluetooth printer in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, printing, escpos

I am using esc_pos_bluetooth package for printing but I cannot print arabic word in it I tried to convert it into image code is
`

```
  List<int> list = description.codeUnits;
          Uint8List data = Uint8List.fromList(list);
          final bytes=data.buffer.asUint8List();
          final image= img.decodeImage(bytes);
           ticket.image(image);
```

`
but this show error like this

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'width' was called on null
```

how can i fix this how can i print arabic word in bluetooth printer.

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] please? We have no idea what `description.codeUnits` is, and your error does not seem to come from this piece of code either.

Comment: decription is arabic word for example 'السلام عليكم'

Comment: Perhaps, this article will help you. [How to print Arabic letters with thermal printer using Flutter esc_pos_printer library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66355251/9014308)

Comment: No i allredy read this article I tried out the solution also but not working

Comment: Is there is any way to print arabic word in bluetooth printing using esc_pos_bluetooth  this package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar issue when trying to print Arabic characters, and I tried several packages. However, I eventually found some useful Flutter SDKs for Thermal Printers that offer support for multiple languages:

- [bluetooth_thermal_printer](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_thermal_printer) - This is a Flutter plugin that allows you to use a Bluetooth thermal printer only for Android devices.
- [blue_print_pos](https://pub.dev/packages/blue_print_pos) - This is a Flutter plugin that enables you to use a POS (point of sale) system on both Android and iOS devices.
  This is the updated forked [blue_print_pos SDK](https://github.com/ankush-ppie/blue_print_pos/) which I used in JAN, 2023. You can use it without facing any issues.

[image: ENGLISH VERSION]

[image: ARABIC VERSION]